# Dynamically format duration in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, time, format, duration

I want to input times that would be displayed in the formats below, depending on whether the digits are needed or not, like this.

```
s.mss
ss.mss
m:ss.mss
mm:ss.mss
```

My main problem is being able to use them to do math with (sum and subtraction only).

- How could I do that?

Look at the [Demo Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qkKmaGvhDhrvMfDojK_TXFmsWA4kfQL_RjA80gOefNA/edit?usp=sharing), *i guess*

**EDIT:** I found a better solution! although its more specific to my use case, so the responses might help you more. But I found that inputing the durations as plain text (as you aren't constrained by a single format) and then creating two functions in a custom script (one to convert text to number, the other the reverse) works much better, as I'm free to use them as numbers or text when needed.

```js
// [hh:][mm:][s]s.mss
function TTIME(text) {
  var value = 0;
    
  str = "" + text;
  if (str.length == 0) return str;
  str = str.split(":")

  switch(str.length) {
    case 3:
      value += Number(str[str.length-3])*60*60;
    case 2:
      value += Number(str[str.length-2])*60;
    case 1:
      value += Number(str[str.length-1]);
  }
  
  return value;
}

function PRETTYTIME(time) {
  var value = Number(time);
  var return_string = "";

  if (value >= 3600) {
    return_string += Math.floor(value/3600) + ":";
    value = value % 3600;
    if (value/60 < 10) return_string += "0";
  } if (value >= 60) {
    return_string += Math.floor(value/60) + ":";
    value = value % 60;
    if (value < 10) return_string += "0";
  } return_string += value.toFixed(3);
  
  return return_string;
}
```

Comment: In the same cell?

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: @marikamitsos added a demo sheet, but theres not really much i can do there? i just want to properly sum these times (they are currently in different formats, but i wanted to have a single one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**01 Display Time**
To get the duration displayed as needed.

```
s.mss
ss.mss
m:ss.mss
mm:ss.mss
```

> You need a separate column `D`, **paste** this formula in `D2`, Take a look at [This Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15dhywQ3kzir3d9uyzc8F7PrPhoAMMyJukfxqokwxVHk/edit?usp=sharing).

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="",,REGEXEXTRACT(TEXT(B2:B,"h:mm:ss.000"),"[1-9].+")))
```

[image]

**Explanation**

1 - Format the number in this case Date/Time with [`TEXT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en) function and set format to `"h:mm:ss.000"`.

2 - [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) the output with the regular_expression `"[1-9].+"` meaning check for the first number from the set `[1-9]` all number except `0` zero and `+.` everything behind it.

3 - [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)`(`[`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)`(B2:B="",,` to calculate only when the cells of the range `B2:B` is not empty.

**02 Sum and subtraction**

You can add and subtract normally, Google sheets see math on date and time as numbers, just use the appropriate format like this.

> Go to Format > Numbers > Custom date and time.

[image]

Comment: thank you, that definetly solves the problem.
just wondering, isnt there a way to do that with just format to avoid using an extra column?

Comment: Glad to hear that, dont forget to check back for the explanation and the example sheet